# Data from $http request not updated into ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a service to share data between controllers and a controller to handle $http request in my application. I use list with ng-repeat to display
data and currently have hardcoded JSON data on service. I plan to modify the hardcoded method to get data from server using $http.post and I got the data  but my list is not updated. I have tried adding $timeout but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
app.service("Storage", function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
        var predicate = 'name';
        var reverse = false;

        var content = this;
        content.items = [];
        content.filteredItems = [];
        return {
            requestData: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var data = $.param({
                    json: JSON.stringify({
                        req_type: 'type_1',
                        reg_name: 'name_2'
                    })
                });

                $http.post("http://yourdomain/json.php", data)
                .success(function(data, status) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    deferred.reject(data); 
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            },
            setContent : function(data){
                content.items = data;
            },
            getContentItems : function () {
                return content.items;
            }
        }   
    });
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $window, $filter, $timeout, $http, Storage) {
        $scope.predicate = null;
        $scope.reverse = null;
        this.items = null;

        Storage.requestData().then(function(data) {
            Storage.setContent(data);
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.predicate = Storage.getPredicate();
                $scope.reverse = Storage.getReverse();
                this.items = Storage.getContentItems();
            });
            //$scope.$apply();
            console.log('After11 : ' + JSON.stringify(Storage.getContentItems()));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistake at this line:

```
this.items = Storage.getContentItems();
```

this !=== controller's this

I always create `mv` variable at the top of controller and use `mv` instead of `this` for avoiding this mistake.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .service('Storage', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
    var content = this;
    var items = [];

    this.requestData = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      //TODO Some http request

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(['A', 'B', 'C']);
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.setContent = function(data) {
      items = data;
    };

    this.getContentItems = function() {
      return items;
    };   
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(Storage) {
      var mv = this;

      mv.items = [];

      Storage.requestData().then(function(data) {
          Storage.setContent(data);
          mv.items = Storage.getContentItems();
      });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <ul ng-controller="MainCtrl as mv">
    <li ng-repeat="item in mv.items" ng-bind="item"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm struggling over 3 hours just for this mistake. Thank you very much for pointing this out. By the way, could you provide any link/information regarding to this solution?

Comment: All information that you need is Angular documentation